# NestJS Microservice Exception handling

Tags: microservices, nestjs

I have setup a Microservice Architecture that looks the following:

- api-gateway (`NestFactory.create(AppModule);`)
- service 1 (`NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>`)
- service 2 (`NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>`)
  ...

A Service looks like this:

```
service.controller.ts
service.handler.ts
```

Where `handler` is like a Service in a typical Monolith that handles the logic.

Currently, I am catching Exceptions the following way:

1. The handler makes a call to the database and fails due to a duplicated key (i.e. email).
2. I catch this exception and convert it to an `RpcException`
3. In the ApiGateway I catch the `RpcException` like so:

   ```
       return new Promise<Type>((resolve, reject) => {
          this.clientProxy
           .send<Type>('MessagePattern', { dto: DTO })
           .subscribe(resolve, (err) => {
               logger.error(err);
               reject(err);
           });
       });
   ```
4. Again I have to catch the rejected Promise and `throw an HttpException` to have the `ExceptionFilter` sending a proper error response. Throwing an Error inside the Promise instead of rejecting it doesn't work)

So basically, I have 3 TryCatch Blocks for 1 Exception.
This looks very verbose to me.

Is there any better way or best practice when it comes to NestJS Microservices?

Can we have an `Interceptor` for the rebound messages received by `this.clientProxy.send` and pipe it to send send the error response to the client without catching it 2 times explicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a complete answer to your question, but it's better than nothing. :)

I try to avoid the `.subscribe`, `reject(...)` approach whenever possible.
Even though the `send` method returns an `Observable`, in most cases you expect only 1 response. So, in most cases `.toPromise()` makes sense.
Once it's a promise, you can use the async-await syntax, and you don't have callbacks and you can effectively just catch all exceptions (and rethrow if you want to). It helps a bit.

```
try {
  const payload = { dto: DTO }; 
  const response = await this.clientProxy.send<Type>('MessagePattern', payload).toPromise();
} catch (err) {
  this.logger.error(err);
}
```

On the server side, you can effectively define Interceptors, which are almost identical to the `Interceptors` you would use for API controllers.

```
@MessagePattern(messagePattern)
@UseInterceptors(CatchExceptionInterceptor)
public async someMethod(...) { }
```

You should implement the `NestInterceptor` interface:

```
@Injectable()
export class CatchExceptionInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, stream$: Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
        return stream$.pipe(
            catchError(...)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I moved away from microservices, so I had no chance the check your answer on the project so far.
Being a better developer than I was, I would accept your answer.

The best way to handle this case would be to intercept the exception or rethrow if needed. The interceptor should then convert the exception to the convention of the caller. 

Ideally, all microservices would follow an ISO convention for exceptions anyway.